# Javascript change onmouseover to click

Tags: javascript

I have this working code, I need to change to a click instead of mouseover:

```
var l1OK_WC = false;
var l2OK_WC = false;
function share()
{
   alert('yo');
}
function getIt_wc()
{
   if(l1OK_WC && l2OK_WC)
      window.open('http://google.ca','_self');

   if(!l1OK_WC)
      alert("Click button one");
   else if(!l2OK_WC)
      alert("Click Button two");
}
```

After this, I have this code:

```
onmouseover="javascript:l1OK_WC=true;"
onmouseover="javascript:l2OK_WC=true;"
```

How do I change this part into a click instead of onmouseover.
So they need to click instead of onmouseover.
I have tried changing to onclick but the script does not work anymore. It stays false and always displays the message of "click button one"

Comment: I have tried that, but the script no longer works. It stays false for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: Can you recreate this in a jsFiddle.net example?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, it's just this simple...

```
onclick="javascript:l1OK_WC=true;"
onclick="javascript:l2OK_WC=true;"
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the script no longer works. It stays false for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling getIt_wc()?  What you are doing with the event attribute really isn't calling a function..

Answer (score 1):

You can change the HTML attribute to `onclick`, but that's not really best practice.  Instead, why not attach an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) to the elements in question?

Something along the lines of:

```
// Assuming you've already grabbed the elements and put them in the variable `myElements`
myElements.addEventListener('click', function() {
    l10K_WC = true;
});
```

This lets you centralize your code (so you only need to make one change, instead of many throughout your HTML, as well as helps caching.  For more information, see here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/86595/54164

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
onmouseover="javascript:l1OK_WC=true;"
onmouseover="javascript:l2OK_WC=true;"
```

by

```
onclick="javascript:l1OK_WC=true;"
onclick="javascript:l2OK_WC=true;"
```

For more info see:

[onClick and onMouseOver](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470771)

**Using an event listener:**

```
<input type="button" value="Button 1" id="myButton1"/>
<input type="button" value="Button 2" id="myButton2"/>

<script>
    myButton2.addEventListener("click", function() { alert('button 1 clicked!'; }, false);
    myButton2.addEventListener("click", function() { alert('button 2 clicked!'; }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the script no longer works. It stays false for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to click on? a button, an image, a link, the canvas?

Comment: A button that goes to a link

Comment: Give your button an ID, like: id="myButton" - then add an event listener to it: myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('Click button one');}, false);

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the HTML this way:
          your-element onclick="JavaScript code"

or use JavaScript to fire it...
          object.onclick=function(){JavaScript Code};

If it's in a button you will have to wrap the button around it :-)

Hope this helps...